# Managing focus on custom textfield flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a general textfield which I am using throughout the app for text inputs and forms. But textfield focus is making the whole form unnatural. To manage focus, I am doing these steps. 
First, on MaterialApp:

```
GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
      },
      child: GetMaterialApp()
),
```

Then custom textfield:

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomTextField(
      {this.title,
      this.controller,
      this.hint,
      this.hide,
      this.maxlines,
      this.minLines,
      this.validator,
      this.onChanged});
  final title, controller, hint, hide, maxlines, minLines, validator, onChanged;

  @override
  _CustomTextFieldState createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //color: Color(0xffE4E5EA),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            onEditingComplete: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            },
            validator: widget.validator,
            controller: widget.controller,
            obscureText: widget.hide ?? false,
            maxLines: widget.maxlines ?? 1,
            minLines: widget.minLines ?? 1,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: widget.hint,
              labelText: widget.title,
              hintStyle: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .bodyText2
                  .apply(color: Colors.grey),
              labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.apply(
                  color: Colors.grey[600]),
              contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
               focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                   borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.blueAccent)),
               enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                   borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[400], width: 1.5)),
               border: OutlineInputBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                   borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200], width: 1.5)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

It works for the most part but when I try to do some task like pick date or file or something, the last used textfield gains focus and keyboard opens. Is there any way to manage focus better way?